# Parse array based on variable and nth character

Tags: arrays, bash

Looking to be able to parse an array based on a variable and take the next 2 characters

```
array=( 7501 7302 8403 9904 )
```

> if var = 73, result desired is 02
>   if var = 75, result desired is 01
>   if var = 84, result desired is 03
>   if var = 99, result desired is 04

Sorry if this is an elementary question, but I've tried variations of cut and grep and cannot find the solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this search function using `printf` and `awk`:

```
srch() {
    printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | awk -v s="$1" 'substr($1, 1, 2) == s{
    print substr($1, 3)}' ;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
srch 75
01

srch 73
02

srch 84
03

srch 99
04
```

Comment: This *works*, to be sure, but it's a pretty significant amount of runtime expense on the lookup side, no?

Comment: This is one of the simplest `awk` and that too is using a non-regex search. Haven't benchmarked it but should't be bad.

Comment: Hmm. If it really *is* just two-digit keys, you're right that we can't have inputs so long that the difference between O(1) and O(n) is all that big in practice; probably would be sticking in the space where startup and subshell/pipeline costs are the main drivers. OTOH, if this lookup is done inside a tight loop (ie. one per line of input), then we could get to a place where calls can add up, just from the aforementioned constant-factor expenses.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: 1e+37 iterations (awk: r:0.573s, u:0.276s, s:0.253s) vs (map: r:0.215s, u:0.104s, s:0.079s)

Comment: Thanks for this benchmark. Above function will become faster if I run `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" > tempFIle.tmp` and then keep only `awk -v s="$1" 'substr($1, 1, 2) == s{
    print substr($1, 3)}'  tempFIle.tmp` in the function body.

Comment: @l'L'l, might I ask for implementation details on that test? I'd like to reproduce -- I'm seeing a much bigger difference than that between `for ((i=0; i<1000000; ++i)); do : "${replacements[37]}"; done` -- at 15.4s per million iterations -- and `for ((i=0; i<1000000; ++i)); do srch 37; done >/dev/null` (which I'm too impatient to let complete before posting this comment).

Comment: ...and, of course, *capturing* the result is even a bit slower -- `result=${replacements[37]}` adds no extra expense, but `result=$(srch 37)` requires creating a subshell.

Comment: (...giving up on getting a response from the million-lookup case after 20 minutes of wall-clock runtime -- including 3 minutes of CPU time inside the parent interpreter responsible for calling all the awk instances alone).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sorry, I was away for a few minutes. You have to consider the test I ran was on a cray xe6, so it was blazingly fast. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/27859e55f9726619f339db0fb96d0b30. I shortened up the loops since you're probably not on a cray :) I think you'll see a drastic difference between the map method and awk in normal setting in the time it actually takes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It was also 10 undecillion... Here's 9999 iterations on a quad-core xeon: (awk: r:1m41.282s, u:0m50.575s, s:0m52.960s) vs (map: r:0m1.296s, u:0m1.240s, s:0m0.055s).

Answer (score 2):

Since bash arrays are sparse, even in older versions of bash that don't have associative arrays (mapping arbitrary strings as keys), you could have a regular array that has keys only for numeric indexes that you wish to map. Consider the following code, which takes your input array and generates an output array of that form:

```
array=( 7501 7302 8403 9904 )

replacements=( )                    # create an empty array to map source to dest
for arg in "${array[@]}"; do        # for each entry in our array...
  replacements[${arg:0:2}]=${arg:2} # map the first two characters to the remainder.
done
```

This will create an array that looks like (if you ran `declare -p replacements` after the above code to dump a description of the `replacements` variable):

```
# "declare -p replacements" will then print this description of the new array generated...
# ...by the code given above:
declare -a replacements='([73]="02" [75]="01" [84]="03" [99]="04")'
```

You can then trivially look up any entry in it as a constant-time operation that requires no external commands:

```
$ echo "${replacements[73]}"
02
```

...or iterate through the keys and associated values independently:

```
for key in "${!replacements[@]}"; do
  value=${replacements[$key]}
  echo "Key $key has value $value"
done
```

...which will emit:

```
Key 73 has value 02
Key 75 has value 01
Key 84 has value 03
Key 99 has value 04
```

---

Notes/References:

- See [the bash-hackers wiki on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for understanding of the syntax used to slice the elements (`${arg:0:2}` and `${arg:2}`).
- See [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) or [the BashGuide on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for more details on the syntax used above.

Comment: Nice solution, question: what happens if you have duplicate entries (e.g.. [73] x 2)?

Comment: @l'L'l, the latter overwrites the former. I don't see anything specified in the question that that behavior would conflict with.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose correct behavior depends on what the OP wants -- the way I read the `awk`-based answer, it would print suffixes for both matching entries if you had a duplicate. Could extend this to do likewise, if desired (or extend the `awk` answer to use first or last match only), but probably worth getting an explicit spec.